# How can I know the last object when I reflect?

Tags: java, reflection

I have a DTO like this,

```
ADto{
  BDto bDto;
  Cto cDto;
}

BDto{
  String a1;
  String b1;
  int b1;
}

CDto{
  String a2;
  String b2;
  int b2;
}
```

When I use reflect,I want to get the `BDto` and `CDto` in `ADto` Object.Code like this:

```
 for (Field field : aObj.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            try {
                Object fieldValue = field.get(object);
 //todo  how to collect all String value  in `BDto` and `CDto` of aObj
                if (fieldValue instanceof String) {
                    shouldCheckFieldValues.add((String) fieldValue);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("some error has happened when fetch data in loop", e);
            }

        }
    }
```

I want to collect all String value in `BDto` and `CDto` of aObj?How can I achieve this? Or how can I know the field which I have to recursive traversal with no hard code?

Comment: Does your title have anygthing to do with your question?

Answer (score 0):

You directly try to get the String attributes from ADto class, you can't.

First get the BDto attribute, then retreive Strings attributes. Do the same for CDto attribute

```
for (Field field : aObj.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        try {
            Object fieldValue = field.get(object);
            //todo  how to collect all String value  in `BDto` and `CDto` of aObj
            if (fieldValue instanceof BDto) {
                for (Field field2 : fieldValue.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) 
                    if (field2 instanceof String) {
                        shouldCheckFieldValues.add((String) field2 );
```

Comment: I want to extract a common reflectUtil,not with detail DTO hard code like `BDto`.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
static void exploreFields(Object aObj) {
    for (Field field : aObj.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {

        try {
            Object instance_var = field.get(aObj);
            if (instance_var instanceof String) {
                System.out.println(instance_var);

            } else if(!(instance_var instanceof Number)) {
                exploreFields(instance_var);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("some error has happened when fetch data in loop", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Edited based on comment. Be aware your objects should not have circular dependencies.

Comment: not only two Dto,may be have XDto in BDto.It is Nested.